# assigned variable gets 'UnboundLocalError'

Tags: python, variables, local

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment.
That is the error I got from my code, but my 'i' is in local range still.

the fuction factor2(n) works by itself. but when put in a for loop, it throw the error. I know there is something behind this, but I can not figure out.

```
def tri_num(n):
    return n * (n + 1) // 2


def factors2(n):
    f_ = 1
    for i in range(2, int(n ** .5) + 1):
        count_ = 0
        while n % i == 0:
            count_ += 1
            n /= i
        if count_ != 0:
            f_ *= count_ + 1
    else:
        if n > i:
            f_ *= 2
    return f_


import itertools
for n in itertools.count(1):
    m = tri_num(n)
    q= factors2(m)
    if q > 500:
        print(m,q)
        break


*

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-52-07bebaa60ddd> in <module>()
          2 for n in itertools.count(1):
          3     m = tri_num(n)
    ----> 4     q= factors2(m)
          5     if q > 500:
          6         print(m,q)

    <ipython-input-51-214ce9ab60ad> in factors2(n)
          9             f_ *= count_ + 1
         10     else:
    ---> 11         if n > i:
         12             f_ *= 2
         13     return f_

    UnboundLocalError: local variable 'i' referenced before assignment
```

*

> 'else:' is part of the for loop, it should not throw an error

```
s = factors2(81)
print(s)
```

give me my answer '5', no error for that.

my script should work and give me two numbers

> UPDATE: Thank you, I figured out. It is a bug in my factors2(), it fail to function when n = 0, 1 and 2. it will be fixed

Comment: The error is from `if n > i` in the [`else` *of the* `for`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html) - probably bad indenting. Such an `else` is therefor "not inside" the `for`, and the error makes sense. In the future, pay attention to (and report) the *exact* error message, indicating lines when relevant.

Comment: 'else:' is part of the for loop. it runs ok as a standalone function

Comment: Python says that statement is incorrect. I'm counting on Python being correct.

Comment: What's `n`? If `range` returns an empty sequence, then nothing will ever be assigned to `i`, and the `else` clause of the loop will be entered.

Comment: If `n == 1`, then you call `range(2, 2)`, which is indeed empty.

Comment: A simpler reproducer would do a lot of good towards getting this question some respect. Here's an example of much shorter code that demonstrates the same problem for the same reason: https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/8ac671dc963ba648a6e611858f0a75a6

Comment: BTW, there's a "delete" button you can use if you want to withdraw the question. (That's frowned on after there are answers, but acceptable right now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are iterating over an empty range, which means `i` is never assigned to before you enter the `for` loop's `else` clause.

For instance, the first value yielded by `count` is 1. Then `tri_num(1) == 1`, so `factors2` gets called with `n == 1`. This results in a call to `range(2, int(1**.5)+1)`, which results in `range(2,2)` which is indeed empty. Since the iterator never yields a value, `i` is never assigned to, and the `else` clause is entered, where you assume `i` *does* have a value. QED.